# Set same y-lim for multi panel facet ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet

I'm generating a facetted plot and I want to set the same y lim axis (0,250000) for all panels but keeping the x axis in the same format as below 
[image: facet_plot]

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(seqDepthDF_melt,aes(x=SampleID,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=Step))+
  ylab("Million PE reads") +
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~ SampleName,scales = "free")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size=rel(0.7)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=3, name="GrandBudapest1"))
```

Would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `facet_wrap` says:

`scales`: 
Should scales be fixed ("fixed", the default), free ("free"), or free in one dimension ("free_x", "free_y")?

Thus, when you specify "free_x" it is free in x dimension, but provides the same scale for all plots on the y-dimension.

We can demonstrate this using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ am) +
  ggtitle("Fixed scales")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ am, scales = "free") +
  ggtitle("Free scales")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ am, scales = "free_x") +
  ggtitle("Free scales on x-axis")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot. It worked after using the specification                                                   "facet_wrap(~ SampleName,scales = "free_x")"